# Getting error QUOTA EXCEEDED while authentication Even if we're using Blaze plan

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are using firebase service for verifying users numbers which was working fine few days ago. But now it suddenly sometimes work and sometimes doesn't and throws error message Quota_Exceeded. I understand our users have increased but we using Blaze plan. Any help please!!

[image]

Comment: Did you find the root cause of this issue? I am also facing this issue now

Answer (score 0):

Did you update quota size for mobile auth?

[image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UQ8w.png

Comment: No i didn't, I have set it to 1000 / hour now.

Comment: it says that quote increase will be available during a particular duration which i set it to 7 days. What happens after that period, would it get back to 100/hour once again ?

Comment: unfortunately, seven days get back same quota